# How to call UnitySendMessage method in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, unity-game-engine

I tried calling UnitySendMessage method in my iOS Framework project using swift language but it is showing this error-

**Use of unresolved identifier 'UnitySendMessage'**

Here is the code snippet for my swift file-

```
import Foundation

@objc public class Example : NSObject{

    @objc open static let shared = Example()

    @objc open func printMsg(){
        print("\(#function) is called with message:");
        UnitySendMessage("CallbackTarget", "OnCallFromSwift", "Hello, Unity!");
    }
}
```

Getting stuck here, can you please tell me what am I missing?

Comment: Check this : https://medium.com/@SoCohesive/unity-how-to-build-a-bridge-ios-to-unity-with-swift-f23653f6261

Comment: Dharmesh, Thanks for sharing the article. I tried this approach, it works if I create a swift file in iOS project generated by building through Unity but it's not working if I create a swift file in my iOS framework project.

Answer (score 3):

check Answer [here](http://answers.unity.com/answers/261308/view.html).

> UnitySendMessage is in libiPhone-lib.a, and as far as I can tell, the
>   Unity folks don't include any header that declares it.
>
> I just added the following to my code
>
> extern void UnitySendMessage(const char *, const char *, const char
>   *);
>
> If you look at the generated AppController.mm, they basically do the
>   same thing for the various UnitySendXXX functions, rather than
>   including a header.
>
> Having said that, while you will be able to build a library that calls
>   UnitySendMessage, that library probably won't work unless it's linked
>   into a Unity project, since UnitySendMessage is going to require more
>   than just libiPhone-lib.a to actually work.

Comment: Thanks, but how to add libiPhone-lib.a in my framework project

Comment: Where to paste extern void UnitySendMessage(constchar *, constchar *, constchar *);...I pasted at the top of UnityAppController.mm but getting an error "Unknown type name 'constchar' ".

Answer (score 0):

Just add this code to your Bridging-Header.h file:

```
#import "UnityInterface.h"
```

Make sure that your files are in the XCode project that was build from Unity, so the actual UnityInterface file that is created by unity is present.

Worked for me :)